# Importing a file .py from your github

Tags: python, github

I am creating a Pipeline to run a randomForest and this particular Pipeline has a Customized Transformer (as a class).
I am using joblib to save up the model and load it afterwards.
The inconvenience is when I load it, it does not recognize the Customized Transformer. So that, I created a .py containing the class but I wondered how can I take it from my github Repository and run it in my python scipt.

```
from joblib import dump, load
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: `git clone url_to_repository`?

Comment: I do not know why but git is not recognized in python script

Comment: python script is not like your terminal. You should use the `os` library and write `os.system("git clone your-rep")`